# How to get product count from parent in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, model

a'm new in django, I have one model like this

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

Parent - foods
subparent - Italian food, French food and other
pizaa, Polenta, Lasagna

Parent - drinks
subparent  - juice, alkohol
water, tea, leamon tea

Can i count in serializer foods count - 3
drinks count - 4

Comment: I recommend packages like https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt for multi-level parent/child models. This includes many built-in features. Otherwise it might be easier to build a class for each category. This might be easier to maintain and understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this ?

```
class Category(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    no_of_children = serializer.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('title', 'no_of_children',)
    
    @staticmethod
    def prefetch_related(queryset):
        return queryset.annotate(
            no_of_children=Count('children')
        )
```

Remember to call `prefetch_related` method in your view eg.

`queryset = serializer.prefetch_related(Category.objects.all())`